# Pydoop vs Mrjob for image processing on Hadoop

Tags: python, hadoop, image-processing

I want to process images(most probably in big sizes) on **Hadoop** platform but I am confused about which one to choose from the aforementioned 2 interfaces, especially for someone who is still a beginner in Hadoop. Considering the need to **split the images into blocks** to distribute processing among working machines and merge the blocks after processing is completed.
It's known that **Pydoop** has better access to the Hadoop API while **mrjob** has powerful utilities for executing the jobs, which one is suitable to be used with this kind of work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually suggest pyspark because it natively supports binary files.

For image processing, you can try TensorFlowOnSpark

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so you think image processing on Hadoop is a bad choice in my case or not recommended? I have the idea that Spark works fine with streaming data with the need for more RAM capacity, unlike Hadoop which works better with batch processing.
I understand that native support of binary files by Spark looks to have big advantages while working, but is it really not recommended to use Hadoop for my case?

Comment: Kafka is meant for Streaming. Spark works fine with Batch. You don't even need Hadoop HDFS/YARN to work with Spark. You could read images from S3 for example

Comment: At first, I thought that Hadoop is more suitable to do such work, but after googling on the net It seemed that switching to Spark is a better choice for my research in my case compared to Hadoop just like you mentioned. I am looking forward to seeing more explanations about the recommended way to achieve such works from people who are experts or may know about this domain.
Thanks again

Comment: Hadoop is over a decade old when cloud wasn't as popular. Spark and other tools have evolved faster in those spaces. HDFS is still popular. YARN not so much